# Matlab - How to create a vector with power sequence

Tags: matlab, vector

How can I create a vector that is

```
2^1, 2^3, 2^5,..., 2^19
```

I tried to use  `V = logspace( log(2)/log(10) , 19*log(2)/log(10) , 10 )` but it didn't work.

Comment: in which way did it not work for you?

Comment: what do you mean by "it didn't work"? It is correct even though not the easiest way to express it.

Answer (score 7):

create the sequence of the exponents and then raise them:

```
2.^(1:2:19)
```

Comment: Your way is much more comfortable.
Thanks :)